# should we use same google-services.json for both ios and Android in firebase?

Tags: android, ios, firebase

We are developing app for both Android and iOS. we are implementing firebase analytics as well as crashlytics. I am not sure if we have to create diff. google-services.json for iOS and android or should we use same in both?

Comment: I think no because you have a different packages on both side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each platform has a different config file.  Android uses google-services.json, and iOS has GoogleService-Info.plist.  You get them separately from the console, and they can't be interchanged.